# How to index PDF Document on Apache Solr

Tags: java, pdf, solr, document

I am new at Solr. Since l could not understand anything by looking at other topics, their explanations were so much professional for me and l am looking for basic explanation about indexing PDF Documents into Solr.

l found this link from some stackoverflow topics, but it is not a tutorial.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler

l just would like to add many pdf documents into solr and search & download them.

How can l do this and do l have to create a java project on eclipse or anywhere ?

Comment: I wonder why l got -2...

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at one of the tutorials out there, like for example Solr in 5 minutes, here[1] the link.

Normally, Solr, like ElasticSearch allow to index OTB without any code to write, so via simple configuration files you should be able to point the folder to index; in some case, the CLI tool should allow you to specify on the command line such information.

Anyway, the easiest way to doing that with Solr consists in using the 'post.jar':

```
cd example/exampledocs
java -Dc=techproducts -jar post.jar sd500.xml
```

to add sd500.xml. If you have multiple files, a simple bash script to loop over them and post to Solr.

Hope it helps!

[1] http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html

[2] https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I convert PDF file to XML then post xml file to solr ?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use the same approach with PDF files. I believe that Solr will pick the right parser for you OTB.

Comment: I am using Solr 4.10.2, l found post.jar and 1 pdf file in exampledocs and moved them to my folder which l created. 
l am in my folder on terminal
alican@alican:~/Downloads/solr-4.10.2/example/solr/senior$
then printed this one, 
java -Dc=senior -jar post.jar solr-word.pdf
lt showed me this message:

Comment: SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file solr-word.pdf
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: <response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe5 (at char #10, byte #-1)</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>

Comment: SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..

there are some errors

Comment: @FLap1x, there's something wrong in the POST, since I read: "[...] using content-type application/xml[...]'. I believe, we should follow the tutorial, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool: with '-type <content-type>' we should be able to specify the content.

Comment: Well, For indexing PDF, should l only write this code ? 

bin/post -c gettingstarted a.pdf

bin/post -c FolderName pdfName ?